# Remove duplicates in dataframe pandas based on values of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe of customers with some items, which looks like this:

```
Customer ID     Item
     1         Banana
     1         Apple
     2         Orange
     3         Grape
     4         Banana
     4         Apple
     5         Orange
     5         Grape
     6         Orange
```

What I'm willing to do is to remove all duplicates customers with same items, so the results should look like this:

```
Customer ID     Item
     1         Banana
     1         Apple
     2         Orange
     3         Grape
     5         Orange
     5         Grape
```

As customer 4 has the same items as customer 1. Also customer 6  with 2.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you means. But if you mean duplicates based on the items, you can collect the items for each customer as a *frozenset* (if unique), or *tuple* (if not unique), and then apply `drop_duplicates`; later on do a filter on the original data frame based on the customer ID.

```
df[df["Customer ID"].isin(df.groupby("Customer ID").Item.apply(frozenset).drop_duplicates().index)]
```

[image]

Or if items are not unique and order doesn't matter:

```
df[df["Customer ID"].isin(df.groupby("Customer ID")
                            .Item.apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))
                            .drop_duplicates().index)]
```